# Zoom Background Image with CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, css-transitions

I would like to scale the background image of my div over time, so that it looks like it is zooming in and out (without hovering the mouse over - I'm just looking for the animation to start automatically). But, no matter what I try, the background animation just looks choppy.

If I set the div to scale, then the transition is smooth, but it scales the entire div, not just the background image. For additional information, I am running the most recent version of Chrome, and have tried on both Windows and OS. You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/sdqv19a0/

```
 <div class="site-main-banner">

        <div class="caption">
            <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">

                        <!-- figure -->
                        <figure> <img src="images/signature.png" alt="signature"> </figure>
                        <!-- H1 Heading -->
                        <h1 class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Purposeful design", "Data-driven marketing", "Dynamic branding", "I love it all." ]'> <span class="wrap"></span> </h1>
                        <!-- H2 Heading -->
                        <h2>graphic designer • web designer • analytical marketer</h2>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="theme-btn">view my portfolio</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.site-main-banner {
float:left;
width:100%;
background:url(https://preview.ibb.co/m8kxST/static_banner_new.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size:cover;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
clear: both;
position: relative;
text-align:center;
overflow: hidden;
animation: shrink 5s infinite alternate steps(60);
}
@keyframes shrink {
0% {
background-size: 110% 110%;
}
100% {
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
}
.site-main-banner a.theme-btn {
color: #FFFFFF;
border:#FFFFFF solid 1px;
background:none;
box-shadow:none;
}
.site-main-banner a.theme-btn:hover {
color: #bc6ca7;
border:#FFFFFF solid 1px;
background:#FFFFFF;
box-shadow:none;
}
.site-main-banner .caption {
position: relative;
float: left;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%);
padding:300px 0;

}
.site-main-banner figure {
float:left;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
padding:0 0 15px 0;
}
```

Suggestions? I am open to a js solution, as well, just am not as comfortable with javascript. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make zooming only to background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888091/how-to-make-zooming-only-to-background-image)

Comment: I looked over this, and am aware that the scale property zooms both the background image and the content of the div. My most current attempt is with changing the background size through an animation. The issue im running into is that the animation creates choppy, jerky zooming, rather than zooming smoothly.

Comment: Complain to Chrome, Firefox renders it smooth. The problem seems to lie in their attempt to avoid antialiasing, but their algo mixed with position `center center` just fails. Note that even if unrelated here, you might want to get rid of `steps` if you want smoothness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate your background into its own element behind the main banner so you can apply keyframe animations transforming the scale of the background individually instead.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-space-background {
  position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%;
  background: #1A1939 no-repeat center center;
  background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/m8kxST/static_banner_new.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
  animation: shrink 5s infinite alternate steps(60);
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.2)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="site-space-background"></div>
<div class="site-main-banner">
    <!-- The rest -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Animating background images have been known to be jerky or rough

Comment: This worked perfectly! I also deleted out the steps(60) and it's smooth and runs great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the css `transform` property in combination with a pseudo element.

```
.site-main-banner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.site-main-banner:after {
    content: “”;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(...);
    // put your animation here
}
```

I can’t really send you a fully working example as I’m currently on my phone in the subway but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried it and it works well, but the animation is still jerky - it doesnt zoom in/out smoothly.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to tell you, animate the transform: scale() property instead of the background-size.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `transform: scale([values]);` in your animation.
Using `transform` element is good for applying scales animation.
Look at this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alvinching28/sdqv19a0/34/). I tweaked some of your code (not that much since I only edited your css animation).

Comment: You could also increase the animation speed so it would look nice.